# What is HTTP LINK Method?

Tags: typescript, express

I have a new web project in my hands. It has REST API built with express and frontend with React. I was about to convert this express side to TypeScript and while doing it, I found some LINK methods there being used, which is not usable in TypeScript by default when importing Router from express.

code example:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = Router();

/**
 * LINK link product material
 */
router.link('/:username/product', async (req, res) => {
    const serviceInstance = new userService(req);
    await serviceInstance.linkProductMaterial();
    return res.json(serviceInstance.result());
});
```

Typescript shows error on the router.link method:

```
Property 'link' does not exist on type 'Router'.ts(2339)
```

Frontend seems to use the same 'link' method when doing a request on the endpoint.

It seems like the method is used to tell when to link two entities together, but other than that I see no reason to use it over GET request.

Is there any reason to use such 'LINK' method and does this have some drawbacks?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Methods/Link.html  https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-snell-link-method-01.html#rfc.section.2 TIL

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Sergio Tulentsev comment I was able to find enough information regarding HTTP LINK method.

Without understanding much about the consequences yet(no testing has taken place), I decided to extend the Express types with module declarations. I only extended the interfaces because I know the express router was working before with the "link" method.

Here is the module declaration (Warning!!! may not work when compiled):

```
// src/custom-types
import { Express } from 'express-serve-static-core';

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
    interface Router {
        link: (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]) => Router;
        unlink: (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]) => Router;
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/custom-types",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  }
}
```

Now there is no errors show in the editor when using router.link and router.unlink methods.